NiceMatrix Right Margin elements
I have been struggling to figure out what is wrong with my code. I currently have a matrix with some colors and on the margin, I would like arrows. At the moment I currently have this
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning,fit, decorations.pathreplacing}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead,paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
\[
\NiceMatrixOptions{xdots={horizontal-labels,line-style = <->}}
\setlength\arraycolsep{6pt}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}%
[   margin,
    last-col,
  ]
\Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,9} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
\Block[fill=blue!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,9} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
\Block[fill=green!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,9} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
\Block[fill=brown!15,rounded-corners]{2-12}{} a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,9} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\[
\NiceMatrixOptions{xdots={horizontal-labels,line-style = <->}}
\setlength\arraycolsep{6pt}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}%
[   margin,
    last-col,
  ]
\Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{11} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{19} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & \Vdotsfor{3}^{\text{State 1}}\\
\Block[fill=blue!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{21} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & \\ 
\Block[fill=green!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{21} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & \\
a_{2,1} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \Vdotsfor{3}^{\text{State 2}}\\
a_{2,1} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
a_{2,1} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,10} & a_{1,11} & a_{1,12} & \\
\Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{71} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & \Vdotsfor{3}^{\text{State 3}}\\
\Block[fill=blue!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{71} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & \\
\Block[fill=green!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{71} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & \\
\Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{71} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & \Vdotsfor{3}^{\text{State 3}}\\
\Block[fill=blue!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{71} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & \\
\Block[fill=green!15,rounded-corners]{1-12}{} a_{71} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} & \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{figure}
\end{document}

The first figure currently bleeds into the margin. Moreover, the second figure is almost an exact replica of the first, but when I want to add vertical arrows, I obtain an error "Missing = inserted for \ifnum." and "Missing number, treated as zero." Additionally, the last column is merged with the margin. Is there anything that can be done to fix this?

Welcome to TeX.SE! please make your code snippets compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Add \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}

Adding the \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{25} does nothing for me. What does this in fact do?

With \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}, I have no error when I compile yor MWE. I think that your TeX installation is not up to date. If you Overleaf, you should upload the latest version of the file nicematrix.sty in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty

This was indeed the problem! Thank you for the help.

You should close the question since the problem is solved.

So indeed there is a problem with Overleaf where the nicematrix package is not updated to the latest version. Uploading the file nicematrix.sty to my Overleaf project fixed the problem. The file can be found on the SVN server of TeXLive: www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty
